# Why hover does not work in delegated event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I am adding some elements dynamically and assigning a hover property to it in delegated event handlers for which I used below code and it did not work.

```
$(document).on("hover", ".sec_close_fast", function() {
  $(this).parent('div').parent('div').css("border", "3px solid #000000");
});
```

Then I used `mouseover` and it worked:

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".sec_close_fast", function() {
  $(this).parent('div').parent('div').css("border", "3px solid #000000");
});
```

I would like to know why `hover` does not work, yet `mouseover` does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function / event `.hover` is not actually an event, but just a shorthand for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. From the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/hover/):

> The `.hover()` method binds handlers for both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during the time the mouse is within the element.

So you cannot use it to "delegate" events.

**Solution**

As you have already mentioned and as it is mentioned in the docs, you can use:

```
$(static_parent).on("mouseenter mouseleave", element, function (e) {
  if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
    // check if it is mouseenter, do something
  } else {
    // if not, mouseleave, do something
  }
});
```