# css hover vs jquery mouseenter+mouseleave

Tags: jquery, css

which one is the best to use, css hover or jquery mouseenter+mouseleave?
I find that css hover is better and make sense for me because i i only need to write 1 line of code( hover) vs 2 lines of code( .mouseenter() + .mouseleave)

Comment: if all you need to do is make style changes, then of course the css hover would make more sense.. if you need to do some other stuff that js would need to do, then js would make sense

Comment: The `.hover()` function is a shorthand of `mouseenter` + `mouseleave`. In your case, it is better to use CSS as DOM Manipulation using JavaScript is not performant enough.

Comment: `I find that css hover is better and make sense for me` - sorted then.

Comment: Also have a look at: [Why hover does not work in delegated event handlers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34991316/why-hover-does-not-work-in-delegated-event-handlers/34991347#34991347)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing some simple styling then the css hover is the way to go. The benefit of jQuery/Javascript is that the events can be used to do things other than styling.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are trying to do. If you are just styling an element based on hover then CSS is the way to go. If you are wanting to add a class to the element for example you would use jQuery mouseenter and mouseleave.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your requirement.. Both are different.. For css related stuff go with hover.. for scripting you have to go with jquery